# How to have conditional statement in JPA during join column or mapped by

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Here is what I want to achieve

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN i18n_resort i18n2_ ON
resort1_.resort_id = i18n2_.resort_id AND i18n2_.LANGUAGE_ID = 2
```

Is it possible to one column and another column with value that act as a conditional statement in JPA.

Below is the entity class of Resort.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resort")
public class Resort implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "resort_id")
  private Long resortId;

  @BatchSize(size = 50)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "resortId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @I18nCollection
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<I18nResort> i18n;

  public Long getResortId() {
    return resortId;
  }

  public void setResortId(Long resortId) {
    this.resortId = resortId;
  }

  public List<I18nResort> getI18n() {
    return i18n;
  }

  public void setI18n(List<I18nResort> i18n) {
    this.i18n = i18n;
  }

}
```

Another class that is joined :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "i18n_resort")
public class I18nResort extends I18nEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(columnDefinition = "i18n_resort_id", name = "i18n_resort_id")
  private Long i18nResortId;

  @Column(name = "resort_id")
  private Long resortId;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  private Long languageId;

  public Long getI18nResortId() {
    return i18nResortId;
  }

  public void setI18nResortId(Long i18nResortId) {
    this.i18nResortId = i18nResortId;
  }

  public Long getResortId() {
    return resortId;
  }

  public void setResortId(Long resortId) {
    this.resortId = resortId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

When I join on i18n resort class at that time i also want to put conditional statement on language_id to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below no need to write query use JPA repository method bas below.

And you add @ManyToOne on child Tabel also.

```
List<Resort> findByI18nLanguageId(Long languageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to go JPQL/ Native query in this scenario that you need to define in a repository class. here is a very good resource to write these queries [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)